# Multiplication between arrays of different shape in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, multiplication

I am new on Python and I don't know exactly how to perform multiplication between arrays of different shape.
I have two different arrays `w` and `b` such that:

```
W.shape = [32, 5, 20]
b.shape = [5,]
```

and I want to multiply

```
W[:, i, :]*b[i]
```

for each i from 0 to 4. 
How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What si the expected output ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut an array with shape [32,5,20]

Comment: @MaurizioSerra What? The expected output is `[32,5,20]`? Then why not return `W` itself?

Comment: @Ch3steR because I need to multiply `W[:, i, :] ` times `b[i]` in my code...

Answer (score 2):

You could add a new axis to `b` so it is multiplied accross `W`'s inner arrays' rows, i.e the second axis:

```
W * b[:,None]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  In numpy, you can multiply this way, but only if the shapes match according to some restrictions:

Starting from the right, every component of each arrays' `shape` must be the equal,  `1`, or not exist

so right now you have:

```
W.shape = (32, 5, 20)
b.shape =        (5,)
```

since 20 and 5 don't match, they cant' be broadcast.

If you were to have:

```
W.shape = (32, 5, 20)
b.shape =     (5, 1 )
```

`20` would match with `1` (`1` is always ok) and the `5`'s would match, and you can then multiply them.

To get `b`'s shape to `(5, 1)`, you can either do `.reshape(5, 1)` (or, more robustly, `.reshape(-1, 1)`) or fancy index with `[:, None]`

Thus either of these work:

```
W * b[:,None] #yatu's answer
W * b.reshape(-1, 1)
```